# Circular (Ring) buffer implementation with fast Lookup

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, circular-buffer

I'm looking for a good implementation of Circular/Ring buffer.
But all I can find are implementation based on a Queue

In principle - all I need is a concurrent Dictionary or a Hashset (they both have similar performance, and Queue is terribly SLOW on Lookup), that would store all unique 'hashes' in memory, and check if incoming 'value' is contained in the buffer.

To summarize, does anyone know any existing Circular buffer implementation, that would also be fast doing value lookup`s ?

Comment: It is not clear what your question is. Can you elaborate? (Keep in mind that questions asking us to recommend a library or tool are off-topic here.)

Comment: And the problem with using a concurrent dictionary is?

Comment: I was hoping to find existing implementation, based on Current dictionary. So thought, maybe someone already knew a good one.

Comment: The end result what I'm trying to accomplish - is to have a buffer of unique values, that would store "hashKeys" of all incoming requests on the Web App. And IF the SAME 'hash' is encountered (within 1 hour or withing last 100.000 values), would result in HTTP 401

Comment: Find code that implements an "LRU cache". Such a cache needs both fast lookup, and the ability to throw away older entries when limit is reached.